# Different pronunciations of "-ead"/"-ed"/"-aid" words

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, speech, vowels, ipa

I find that American/British English dialects tend to pronounce words like "*bed*", "*red*", "*dead*", "*bred*", "*said*", etc. with the exact same vowel sound: the IPA **ɛ** vowel (- and so this question may seem a bit odd to some of you). However, where I come from (Singaporean English), there is a clear distinction in the correct pronunciation in normal spoken language, with two categories of words:

1. Pronounced with "**ɛ**", such as "br**e**d", "l**e**d", etc.
2. Pronounced like the **e** in "h**e**y" but ending sharply at he the
   "**e**" without the draggy "**ɪ**" sound, such as "h**ea**d",
   "br**ea**d", "s**ai**d", "r**e**d".

   (This is clearly distinct from
   the "**eɪ**" sound in "*braid*", "*frayed*", "*played*" etc.) For example,
   "*red*" or "*bed*" is much closer to "*rad*" or "*bad*" in
   American/British pronunciations, but that would sound completely
   weird here, where it is much more between "*rad*"/"*bad*" and
   "*raid*"/"*bayed*". (I can't seem to find the IPA for this
   particular sound, however, though it is very prevalent in many
   words)

Does this distinction exist in other dialects too?

Comment: The **eɪ** sound comes in *say* and *stay* (also, *stayed* & *staid*), but not in *said* -- certainly not in *read*.

Comment: "Head" is (or was) pronounced "haid" in some dialects of American English, and "dead" as "daid".  (You may remember Curly in the musical *Oklahoma!* sang "Pore Jud is daid, pore Jud lies daid....")